# Drawing a line in a class which extends "Activity'

Tags: android, imageview, draw, lines

I have an ImageView loading a picture in my Activity and want to draw some lines on it.  It seems like I'm not able to overlay the lines I draw onto the ImageView.  If I create a new class (myPainter) which extends 'View', hook myPainter.onDraw() and then setContentView(mp) in onCreate() from the activity, all I get are the drawn lines. My ImageView is gone from onCreate().  How do I get the ImageView and lines to show up in the same layout?  I'm also Override'ing onTouch() for the ImageView so I can get the xy click locations from it.

```
    public class myPainter extends View
    {
    public myPainter (Context context)
       {
        super (context);
       }

     @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
     {
      super.onDraw (canvas);
      Paint p = new Paint();
          p.setColor(Color.RED);

         canvas.drawLine (E_XMIN, E_YMIN, E_XMAX, E_YMAX, p);
     }
    }


     @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
      super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
      setContentView (R.layout.main);
      ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
      iv.setOnTouchListener (this);

// this draws my lines, but I loose the pic above ^^^
      myPainter mp = new myPainter(this);        
      setContentView(mp);
     }
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I think I've literally painted myself into a corner. How would I add a frameAnimation to this code now in the onTouchEvent() method? Like where the user touches the screen. The Android rocketAnimation example causes an exception if I add code to the myPainter() class:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)
  {

        //Log.d (TAG, "touchevent in myPainter");
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d (TAG, "down x:" + event.getX() + " y:" + event.getY());

                    int wClick = getClick (event.getX(), event.getY());


                    AnimationDrawable touchAni;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById (R.drawable.triangle);
                    iv.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.nova);
                    touchAni = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground ();
                   touchAni.start ();

                   return true;
        }

       return super.onTouchEvent (event);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement the suggestions above, but could not get the functionality I was aiming for.  Perhaps I've not framed my question completely, or just a general misunderstanding.  I ended up adding a setBackgroundResource() in the myPainter main method to get the image on the screen. I think I've got it working as needed and posting the code below in case it helps someone else. Thanks for offering your help!

```
    class myPainter extends View implements myConst
    {
        private final static String TAG = "** myPainter **";

        public myPainter (Context context)
       {
           super (context);       
           Log.d (TAG, "new myPainter");
           setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.triangle);
       }

        @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            super.onDraw (canvas);     
            Log.d (TAG, "new myPainter");

            Paint p = new Paint ();
           p.setColor (Color.RED);
          canvas.drawLine (E_XMIN, E_YMIN, E_XMAX, E_YMIN, p);
        }


       /** 
         * called to determine what part of the triangle was clicked
         * @param x
         * @param y
         * @return click id from myConst
         */
        private int getClick (float x,  float y)
        {
            int id = 0;
                // insert logic to test x,y locations and return
                // region ID of what was clicked
                ...

            return (id);
        }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)
      {
            Log.d (TAG, "touchevent in myPainter");
switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d (TAG, "down x:" + event.getX() + " y:" + event.getY());

                        int wClick = getClick (event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            }

           return false;
      }

    }
```

And then my main application class has this for onCreate():

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.main);

    myPainter mp = new myPainter(getApplicationContext());
    mp.invalidate ();
    setContentView(mp);

    //ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    //iv.setOnTouchListener (this);

}
```

Comment: what is `myConst`? and where did u get `E_XMIN, E_YMIN` etc

Comment: It doesnt draw over `R.layout.main`. You just basically changed `setContentView`. The `layout.main` is not visible. You just put `myPainter` on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling `setContentView` twice.  Your onCreate should be more like:

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
      super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
      setContentView (R.layout.main);
      ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
      iv.setOnTouchListener (this);
     }
```

Comment: Apologies, but I'm not sure I understand your reply.  This would only display the ImageView and never fire onDraw() in myPaint to get the lines drawn over the top.  Is there a way to hook onDraw() in a class which does *not* extend View?  Guess maybe that's a better question.

Comment: Since you are extending View, then onDraw should be called automatically as it would in any View.  The call to super in your onDraw should paint everything setup from setContentView (which should have your image), then you are doing your custom drawing after that point.

Comment: Also, this line effectively does nothing for you: myPainter mp = new myPainter(this);  You are already inside an instantiated myPainter, so there is no need to instantiate another one with a reference to yourself.